# How to assign name to form in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am making form in CakePHP I want the HTML for that form as below

```
<form action="/abc/sessionapps/login" name="UserLoginForm" id="UserLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Till now I have written following code in CakePHP

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'sessionapps', 'action' =>'login'),array('name'=>'UserLoginForm')));
```

It is generating following output

```
<form action="/abc/sessionapps/login" 0="0" id="UserLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Please Help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', 
   array(
      'url' => array('controller' => 'sessionapps', 'action' =>'login'), 
      'name' => 'UserLoginForm' 
   )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('name'=>'UserLoginForm','url' => array('controller' => 'sessionapps', 'action' =>'login')));
?>
```

Generally we give the model name as the form name so that we get the array as $this->data[Model] and we can save it simply passing this array to the save query.